# NullPointerException when calling a method from a dynamic object array

Tags: java, exception, object

Good day,

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory {

private int allocatedSize = 0;
public Entry[] entryDirectory = new Entry[allocatedSize];

@Override
public void addEntry(Entry newEntry) {
    newEntry = findFreeLocation();

    entryDirectory = Arrays.copyOf(entryDirectory,
            entryDirectory.length + 1);

}

private Entry findFreeLocation() {

    Entry returnedEntry = new Entry();

    for (int i = 0; i < entryDirectory.length; i++) {

        if (entryDirectory[i] == null) {
            break;
        }
        returnedEntry = entryDirectory[i];
    }

    return returnedEntry;
}
```

I've made the size of the entryDirectory dynamic; it increments each time the addEntry method is used. However, when I am trying to call a method of an entry object from the entryDirectory array, a NullPointerException is thrown.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayDirectory d = new ArrayDirectory();

    d.addEntry(new Entry("Jack", "Jones", 1234));
    d.addEntry(new Entry("Brad", "Jones", 1234));
    d.addEntry(new Entry("Olga", "Jones", 1234));

    System.out.println(d.entryDirectory[0].getInitials());
}
```

Here is the getInitials() method of the Entry object.

```
public Entry(String surname, String initials, int extension){
    this.surname = surname;
    this.initials = initials;
    this.extension = extension;
}


public String getInitials() {
    return initials;
}
```

Comment: In which line you are facing the issue ???? or stacktrace ?

Comment: System.out.println(d.entryDirectory[0].getInitials());   mate

Comment: The normal supposition would be that you're attempting to use a null reference for the call.  Identify the line, figure out what reference was used, and figure out why it's null.  This is very basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Philip Voronov's answer, your `findFreeLocation` method is also implemented incorrectly. Assuming null means an absence of value, the proper implementation should be like this:

```
private int findFreeLocation() {
  for (int i = 0; i < entryDirectory.length; i++) {
    if (entryDirectory[i] == null) {
        return i
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
public void addEntry(Entry newEntry) {
  int loc = findFreeLocation();
  if (loc >= 0) {
    entryDirectory[loc] = newEntry;
  } else {
    entryDirectory = Arrays.copyOf(entryDirectory, entryDirectory.length + 1);
    entryDirectory[entryDirectory.length - 1] = newEntry;
  }
}
```

That said, I highly suggest you use a built-in collection, like [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), to handle automatically resizing arrays. They are much easier to use, and their performance is also better (increasing the array size by one means you have to resize every time an item is added, in comparison to ArrayList's implementation, which doubles the size every time it fills up).

Comment: thank you very much! I was quite confused with all this. Thank you very much once again!!!

Comment: I know it is better to use an ArrayList instead but this is a uni assignment and the teacher has told us not to use arraylists. That's why I have used an array here.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign anything as element of your array `entryDirectory`, so `NullPointerException` arises when you try to invoke `getInitials()` on null-value object `entryDirectory[0]`.

---

Remember that if you use `Arrays.copyOf()`,

> for any indices that are valid in the copy but not the original, the
>   copy will contain null

See [Arrays javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29)